# Problem with lifetimes in signature of closure on iter().min_by()

Tags: rust

```
fn rtsp_compare(a: & RTSPUrl, b: & RTSPUrl) -> Ordering {
    if a.resolution.is_some() && b.resolution.is_some() {
        let w = a.resolution.as_ref().unwrap().width;
        let h = a.resolution.as_ref().unwrap().height;
        let _w = b.resolution.as_ref().unwrap().width;
        let _h = b.resolution.as_ref().unwrap().height;
        if w*h > _w*_h {
            Ordering::Greater
        } else {
            Ordering::Less
        }
    } else {
        Ordering::Equal
    }
}
```

I need to calculate the `min_by` using a function, so I created `rtsp_compare` above. I'm trying to use here:

```
let minimum_element = rtsp_urls.iter().min_by(rtsp_compare);
```

but I'm getting:

```
type mismatch in function arguments

expected signature of `for<'r, 's> fn(&'r &liborwellprofile_protobuf_rust::protos::stream::RTSPUrl, &'s &liborwellprofile_protobuf_rust::protos::stream::RTSPUrl) -> _`rustc(E0631)
orwell_message_handler.rs(199, 1): found signature of `for<'r, 's> fn(&'r liborwellprofile_protobuf_rust::protos::stream::RTSPUrl, &'s liborwellprofile_protobuf_rust::protos::stream::RTSPUrl) -> _`
```

Why it expects a signature of `&'r &`? What it even mean?

If I add this into a closure defined inside the min_by, like this:

```
let minimum_element = rtsp_urls.iter().min_by(|a, b| {...});
```

it works. Why? For me this closure would be weaker than a function. I also tried using a closure in the same block as the `let minimum_element =`  line, but it wouldn't work also.

Comment: `.iter()` yields references (`&RTSPUrl`) to the values in the vector. `.min_by()` calls the given function with references to the values from the iterator (`&&RTSPUrl`). You probably should do `|a, b| rtsp_compare(*a, *b)`.

Comment: An alternative to kmdreko's answer is changing the signature to `(a: && RTSPUrl, b: && RTSPUrl)`, it is the signature the compiler is expecting.